# cbind with different rows and disregard extra rows from the 2nd df

Tags: r, merge, cbind

I have this particular data frame

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4), Type1 = c("A","B","A","B")) 
ID  Type1
1       A
2       B
3       A
4       B

df2 <- data.frame(Length = c("0.75","1.25","1.75","2.25","2.75","3.25")) 
Length  
0.75 
1.25
1.75
2.25
2.75
3.25
```

Usually I will use `cbind` to combine the column when they have the same row such as

```
dfnew <- head(cbind(df1, df2), 4)
```

However, the problem occurs when they have different rows, so I was wondering if there are any ways to specify in the `cbind` command to disregard the extra row.

This is the outcome that I am looking for

```
ID  Type1  Length
1       A    0.75
2       B    1.25
3       A    1.75
4       B    2.25
```

Any suggestions? preferably without having to create the whole new data frame for Length

Comment: `dfnew <- cbind(head(df1, 4), head(df2, 4))`

Comment: or `cbind(df1[1:4, ], df2[1:4, ])`. More generally, you could use `cbind(df1[1:min(nrow(df1), nrow(df2)), ], df2[1:min(nrow(df1), nrow(df2)), ])`.

Comment: Cheers, you're welcome

Comment: @lmo Work perfectly as well Thank you!

Comment: @ChiPak @lmo I applied your method with another data (60 obs) and it change the whole data frame to 2 variables (squezzing every variables in df1 in variable1 i.e. the value show up as `c("A","B","A","B"))` in stead of just A or B and put Length into variable 2 `c("0.75","1.25","1.75","2.25"))`) Any idea what is the cause :/ ? It works perfectly with the the smaller data above and I have already specified `dfnew2<- cbind(head(df3, 60), head(df4, 60))`

Comment: This is likely an issue with your data structure. Post the output of `str(df1)` and `str(df2)` into your question above. It may also be helpful to include samples of your data with `dput`, but seeing the structure would be helpful.

Comment: @lmo I have now update the structure

Comment: Your variable, `grouped_df$Mean_Typenw` is a nested list. So you have a nested list as a variable inside of a data.frame (which is a list). This structural complexity can be difficult to work with. An alternative to `cbind` that should work in this instance is `new_df <- grouped_df[1:60,]; new_df$newvar <- df4[, 1]`. Also, your larger object is a `tbl` and these objects behave differently than normal data.frames in some instances, so it is important to note that you are working with tbls rather than data.frames as this has been the root of some problems on SO in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a function that takes two dataframes as input then this should work:

```
unequal_bind <-  function(df1, df2){
len1 <- nrow(df1)
len2 <- nrow(df2)
df_final <- cbind(df1[1:min(len1, len2), ], df2[1:min(len1, len2), ])
df_names <-  c(names(df1), names(df2))
df_final <- setNames(df_final, df_names)
}

df_out <- unequal_bind(df1, df2)

df_out

  ID Type1 Length
  1  1     A   0.75
  2  2     B   1.25
  3  3     A   1.75
  4  4     B   2.25
```